# another way to display data each month and year with mysqli in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have recordeds in my database with UNIX time saved for each.
I'm trying to display each month and year in a different page for statics
Ex:

My database

```
|------id ------- | ----- time ----- | -------name-------|
|------1 -------- | -- 1613916239 -- | -------jack-------|
|------2 -------- | -- 1614261839 -- | ------Mariam------|
|------3 -------- | -- 1614804313 -- | -------tom--------|
```

time for Jack and Mariam is same month and year February 2021, and March 2021 for tom
so, I want to display only who has time
I wrote this code

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM name ORDER BY time;";
  $result = mysqli_query($dBconnection, $sql);
  $check = mysqli_num_rows($result);
  $links = array();
    if ($check>0) {
      while($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $year_month = date("F Y", $data["time"]);
        if (!in_array($year_month, $links)) {array_push($links, strtotime($year_month));}
        echo ' In '.date("F Y", $data["time"]).'<br />';
        // if (date("F", $data["time"])===date("F", time())) {echo $data['name'].' In '.date("F Y", $data["time"]).'<br />';}
      }
    }
  print_r($links);
```

but it's display into array

```
Array ( [0] => 1612126800 [1] => 1612126800 [2] => 1614546000 )
```

it count as a different time !!
so, what's wrong ??

Also, I'm asking is there an easy way like a bring data from with mysqli in month and year that I choose
for example:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM name ***WHERE time is February 2021*** ORDER BY time;";
```

Answer (score 0):

Solve it ...

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM rate WHERE MONTH(time)=3 AND YEAR(time)=2021 ORDER BY time;";
```

to display data with year 2021 and month 3rd

**in my situation. I'm using UNIX time so add this**
fo each time FROM_UNIXTIME(time)

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM rate WHERE MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(time))=3 AND YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(time))=2021 ORDER BY time;";
```